# Correct syntax for nested list or set comprehension

Tags: python, set, list-comprehension

Imagine this object:

```
my_obj = {
    'Episodes' : [
        {'Tags' : ['one','two','three']},
        {'Tags' : ['three','four','five']}
            ]
        }
```

I want to create a set of the tags:

```
tags = set(tag for tag in e['Tags'] for e in my_obj['Episodes'])
```

However, it doesn't work because `e` is not defined.  How can I do it??

Comment: Look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766711/python-advanced-nested-list-comprehension-syntax), which also deals with nested list comprehension syntax

Comment: That other question is about 50 times longer and more complex than my question.  If I was looking for an answer to this question, I know which one I'd rather digest.  No disrespect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tags = set(tag  for e in my_obj['Episodes'] for tag in e['Tags'])
```

you need to change the order and get e first... :)

Answer (score 4):

The trick I use to avoid getting confused by these nested comprehensions is to *expand the loop in the order it appears in the comprehension*.

So in your example, you have a [genex](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

`tag for tag in e['Tags'] for e in my_obj['Episodes']`

Which you can mentally expand into double loop like this:

```
for tag in e['Tags']:
  for e in my_obj['Episodes']:
    yield tag
```

And now with this structure you can quite clearly see where your error lies, with `e` being undefined, and see that it should really be:

```
for e in my_obj['Episodes']:
  for tag in e['Tags']:
    yield tag
```

Which collapses back into the nested comprehension

`tag for e in my_obj['Episodes'] for tag in e['Tags']`

As you have already seen from the previous answers.  Hope this helps!