# How can I make multiple empty lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, empty-list

How can I make many empty lists without manually typing the following?

```
list1=[], list2=[], list3=[]
```

Is there a *for* loop that will make me 'n' number of such empty lists?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 144, accepted):

A [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) is easiest here:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]
>>> lists
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

Be wary not to fall into the trap that is:

```
>>> lists = [[]] * 5
>>> lists
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> lists[0].append(1)
>>> lists
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Comment: Holy wow! we posted this at EXACTLY The same time (mind=blown)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: There should be a badge for that

Comment: This creates a list of lists though, not separate variables with different names. Although it is definitely shorter.

Comment: @alemangui: Creating `n` separate variables with different names is a strong indication that you want a list of lists

Comment: Why does the "trap" happen?

Comment: Because all five elements are the same list - `lists[0] is list[1]` is `True`

Comment: I did fall into the trap and you saved me :) Thanks!

Comment: This trap seems no longer to be the case (at least in python3.6.7).

Comment: @WouterDeCoster: Seems unlikely. Can you run `l = [[]] * 5; [id(i) for i in l]` to prove it?

Comment: @Eric: ah wait, the trap is only an issue in your second snippet. Nevermind, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 59):

If you want to create different lists without a "list of lists", try this:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = ([] for i in range(4))
```

Comment: `list1, list2, list3, list4 = [], [], [], []` is still shorter! TIL you can unpack a generator all at once

Comment: for 4 yes, but it is handy if there are more

Answer (score 17):

Look up [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
listOfLists = [[] for i in range(N)]
```

Now, `listOfLists` has N empty lists in it.

More links on list comprehensions:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418389/list-comprehension)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766711/python-advanced-nested-list-comprehension-syntax)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/python-if-else-in-list-comprehension?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

I see that many answers here get you many lists with no names assigned (as elements of a larger list). This may be not always what's needed.

It is possible to create multiple empty lists, each with a different name/value, using a tuple:

```
a,b,c = ([],[],[])
```

Changing this structure should get you what you want.

Comment: In Python 3, you could also do `a, b, c = [], [], []`.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
def mklist(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield []
```

Usage:

```
list(mklist(10))
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

a, b, c = mklist(3) # a=[]; b=[]; c=[]
```

Answer (score 4):

The code below will dynamically 'create' itself. For every iteration, the following command will issued:

> list**number** = []

Where **number** is the value of *i* in the loop.

```
x = 3 # Amount of lists you want to create
for i in range(1, x+1):
    command = "" # This line is here to clear out the previous command
    command = "list" + str(i) + " = []"
    exec(command)
```

The result of this particular piece of code is three variables: list1, list2 and list3 being created and each assigned an empty list.

You can generalize this to make practically anything you want.
Do note that you cannot put this into a function as far as I know, because of how variables and global variables work.

```
name = "my_var" # This has to be a string, variables like my_var1, my_var2 will be created.
value = "[]" # This also has to be a string, even when you want to assign integers! When you want to assign a string "3", you'd do this: value = "'3'"
amount = 5 # This must be an integer. This many variables will be created (my_var1, my_var2 ... my_var5).

for i in range(1, amount+1):
    command_variable = ""
    command_variable = name + str(i) + " = " + value
    exec(command_variable)
```

Comment: `exec` is almost always a really bad idea. If you think about using this code, then change your mind and don't. At the very least, use `globals()[varname] = val`, if you must dynamically create variables

Answer (score 3):

Or as simple as

```
added, modified, removed, inactive = ([],) * 4
```

Comment: This is nice. A little bit more cryptic than "added, mod, rem, inact = [],[],[],[]" but for sure more compact !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a list of list of list of list... like this too. It won't return any error. But I haven't got any idea what it's used for.

```
n = 5 
>>> lists = [[[]]] for _ in range(n)]
>>> lists
   [[[[]]], [[[]]], [[[]]], [[[]]], [[[]]]]
```