# Automatically generated list not behaving properly

Tags: python, list, loops

I've found a good way of looped list making [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520876/how-can-i-make-multiple-empty-lists-in-python). And the code run just as I needed.

```
x=["alpha","betta", "gamma"]
y=[[] for _ in range(len(x))]
y[1]=3
```

Will give me `[[], 3, []]` as expected. But when I tried to upscale the code:

```
z=[10,20,30]
x=["alpha","betta"]
y=[[] for _ in range(len(z))]
y=[y for _ in range(len(x))]
y[1][1]=4
```

Will give me the correct shape but I will get `[[[], 4, []], [[], 4, []]]`

Instead of `[[[], [], []], [[], 4, []]]` I've obviously fallen into the trap mentioned in the link but I don't understand why and how to avoid this problem

Comment: It's spelled "beta" ;)

Comment: now I'm not sure it's really a duplicate, as OP did the first 2D thing creation properly. The mistake is just passing the same reference over and over again. reopening as OP didn't understand why even by doing some research

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where your code goes wrong:

```
y=[y for _ in range(len(x))]
```

Because you are essentially creating two pointers to the same list (i.e. y). Instead you could try something like this:

```
y=[y.copy() for _ in range(len(x))]
```

Which solves your problem since you create new lists.

Answer (score 1):

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52904725/6451573) fixes the issue you're demonstrating but what if you do this instead:

```
y=[[] for _ in range(len(z))]
y=[y.copy() for _ in range(len(x))]
y[1][1].append(12)
```

here I'm using a list reference instead of overwriting it so I get:

```
[[[], [12], []], [[], [12], []]]
```

Damn. Why this? because `copy` creates a *shallow* copy, you need to `deepcopy`

```
import copy
y=[copy.deepcopy(y) for _ in range(len(x))]
y[1][1].append(12)
```

prints:

```
[[[], [], []], [[], [12], []]]
```

now choose the one that suits your needs best.