# Matrix (Jagged Array) for in loop initialization

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to do an inline uniform distribution initialization, but don't seems to find how to do so, if possible.

My working code is:

```
test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
p = []
for row in test:
    prow = [1.0/(len(row)*len(test)) for x in row]
    p.append(prow)
print p
[[0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111],
 [0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111],
 [0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111]]
```

My question is, is there a way to narrow the "for row in test" to the same form of the second loop and end up with only 1 line? Something like:

```
p = [1.0/(len(row)*len(test)) for x in row for row in test]
print p
[0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111,
 0.1111111111111111]
```

But obviously the right result. Clues?

Comment: You guys are fast! Thanks! Can't even accept the answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, what you're looking for is this:

```
In [13]: test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [14]: p = [[1.0/(len(row)*len(test)) for x in row] for row in test]

In [15]: p
Out[15]: 
[[0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111],
 [0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111],
 [0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111]]
```

PS: You might be interested in [list comprehension syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633)

Answer (score 4):

I think something like:

```
[[1.0/(len(row)*len(test))]*len(row) for row in test]
```

if I'm reading your code correctly.  The magic here is because every element in the row gets the same (immutable) value, you can just create a list of the correct length with the correct value ala `[value]*length`.

Comment: Magic indeed. Hadn't even thought about this approach.