# Understanding list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm sort of new to programming. I have created a class that uses list comprehension in its initializer. It is as follows:

```
class Collection_of_word_counts():
 '''this class has one instance variable, called counts which stores a 
dictionary where the keys are words and the values are their occurences'''

def __init__(self:'Collection_of_words', file_name: str) -> None:
    '''  this initializer will read in the words from the file,
    and store them in self.counts'''
    l_words = open(file_name).read().split()
    s_words = set(l_words)

    self.counts = dict([ [word, l_words.count(word)] 
                        for word 
                        in s_words])
```

I think I did alright for a novice. It works! But I don't exactly understand how this would be represented in a for-loop. My guess was terribly wrong:

```
self.counts =[] 
for word in s_words:
    self.counts = [word, l_words.count(word)]
dict(self.counts)
```

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766711/python-advanced-nested-list-comprehension-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess was not wrong at all; you just forgot to append and assign back to `self.counts`:

```
counts = [] 
for word in s_words:
    counts.append([word, l_words.count(word)])
self.counts = dict(counts)
```

That's what a list comprehension does, essentially; build a list from the loop expression.

You could also translate that to a dictionary comprehension instead:

```
self.counts = {word: l_words.count(word) for word in s_words}
```

or better still, use a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and save yourself all that work:

```
from collections import Counter

def __init__(self:'Collection_of_words', file_name: str) -> None:
    '''  this initializer will read in the words from the file,
    and store them in self.counts'''
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        self.counts = Counter(infile.read().split())
```

The `Counter()` object goes about counting your words a little more efficiently, and gives you additional helpful functionality such as listing the top N counts and the ability to merge counts.

Comment: Delete that before you get a -1 :D

Answer (score 4):

This is what your comprehension is as a `for` loop:

```
dictlist = []
for word in s_words:
    dictlist.append([word, l_words.count(word)])
self.counts = dict(dictlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially creating a dictionary, where the key of the dictionary is the word and the value corresponding to that key is the number of times the word appears.

```
self.counts ={}

for word in s_words:
   self.counts[word] = l_words.count(word)
```