# list iteration with 'i for j in' that I never saw

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what does the following python code do

```
plain_list = [ j for i in arguments for j in i ]
```

I've never seen such a syntax, can someone help me out?

Comment: It's called a list comprehension.  Knowing that, you should be able to look it up.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Advanced list comprehension syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633)

Comment: Note that this is a relatively common idiom for flattening a list of lists (iterable of iterables), often used by people who tend not to import `itertools` for everything (`itertools.chain` can be used to the same end.)

Comment: OP: welcome to Python, where the first step for doing anything is "How can I reduce that to a list comprehension?" Then the second step is "Oh that's ridiculous, I should just use `itertools` instead."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Using normal for-loops, its equivalent code would be:

```
plain_list = []               # Make a list plain_list
for i in arguments:           # For each i in arguments (which is an iterable)
    for j in i:               # For each j in i (which is also an iterable)
        plain_list.append(j)  # Add j to the end of plain_list
```

Below is a demonstration of it being used to flatten a list of lists:

```
>>> arguments = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>>
>>> plain_list = [ j for i in arguments for j in i ]
>>> plain_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> plain_list = []
>>> for i in arguments:
...     for j in i:
...         plain_list.append(j)
...
>>> plain_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```