# First element incorrect in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

If I use:

```
[(x, y) for x in range(5) for y in range(0, x * 6)]
```

I get

```
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13), (3, 14), (3, 15), (3, 16), (3, 17), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (4, 11), (4, 12), (4, 13), (4, 14), (4, 15), (4, 16), (4, 17), (4, 18), (4, 19), (4, 20), (4, 21), (4, 22), (4, 23)]
```

Why is the first element (1, 0)?

Comment: what output do you want exactly?

Comment: I thought it would output (0, 0) as well. Question has been answered, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when `x is 0`, `y in range(0, x * 6)` becomes `y in range(0, 0)`, which is an empty range.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take a look at what the double for loop means:

```
[(x, y) for x in range(5) for y in range(0, x * 6)]
```

is the same as:

```
answer = []
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(0, x*6):
        answer.append((x,y))
```

[[source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633)]

So in the first iteration of `x`, `x` takes the value `0`. Therefore, the inner expression becomes

```
for y in range(0, 0*6)
```

which is the same as

```
for i in range(0, 0)
```

Well, `range(0,0)` has no elements in it. Therefore, the inner loop never creates elements when `x=0`