# two for loops in list comprehension python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
f_array=['1000,1','100,10','100,-10']
```

I am trying to sum up all the first element in each value of the above array. I tried something like:

```
number = sum([ num for num in item.split(",")[1] for item in f_array])
```

but it dint work. What would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Advanced Nested List Comprehension Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766711/python-advanced-nested-list-comprehension-syntax)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: there is actually no need to use nesting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use nested loops then need to swap the order of the `for` loops:

```
number = sum([num for item in f_array for num in item.split(",")[1]])
```

List comprehension loops are listed in *nesting order*, left to right is the same as nesting in regular Python loops:

```
for item in f_array:
    for num in item.split(",")[1]:
```

This still won't work, as `item.split(',')[1]` is a string; you'll end up looping over the characters. If you wanted to sum every second number, just *select* that number:

```
item.split(",")[1] for item in f_array
```

There is no need to loop there as there is no sequence when you selected one element.

You don't actually want to use a list comprehension here; drop the `[...]` square brackets to make it a generator expression, thus avoiding creating an intermediary list object altogether.

You also need to convert your strings to integers if you wanted to sum them:

```
number = sum(int(item.split(",")[1]) for item in f_array)
```

Demo:

```
>>> f_array = ['1000,1', '100,10', '100,-10']
>>> sum(int(item.split(",")[1]) for item in f_array)
1
```

Comment: it does something unexpected. results in ['1', '1', '0', '-', '1', '0']

Comment: You may want to look at the supplied demo. Martijn Pieters was updating while you commented.