# Using enumurate value of second for in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension that returns the filenames of all files in a list of dirs. I've written the following list comprehension which fails since d is not defined at the time of os.listdir(d) on the first iteration. How can I restructure this list comprehension such that it works?

```
[f for f in os.listdir(d) for d in dirs if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, f))]
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633. The `for` expressions have to be in "reverse" order for a nested list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order your `for` loops in the same order you'd nest them; you have them swapped. Move the `for d in dirs` part to the front:

```
[f for d in dirs for f in os.listdir(d) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, f))]
```

If it helps, write out the loops as regular `for` statements first:

```
for d in dirs:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, f)):
            # append f
```

and just join the lines and remove the `:` colons to create the list comprehension order.

Answer (score 1):

You have the logic in reverse

```
[f for d in dirs for f in os.listdir(d)  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, f))]
```

Which is the same as:

```
fles = []
for d in dirs:
    for f in os.listdir(d):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, f)):
            fles.append(f)
```