# Create a list within a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I make this:

`[char for line in grid for i,char in enumerate(line) if len(line[i:])>3]`

return a list of char's for each line that meet the criteria:

`[[char for line in grid] for i,char in enumerate(line) if len(line[i:])>3]` #NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Comment: I think you want `[[char for i,char in enumerate(line) if len(line[i:])>3] for line in grid]`. Take a look at [advanced nested list comprehension syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for -

```
[[char for i,char in enumerate(line) if len(line[i:])>3] for line in grid]
```

You should move the second for loop and condition inside the list, not the first one. When there were no lists, the order of execution was - first for loop - `for line in grid` -> second for loop - `for i,char in enumerate(line)` .

The above would preserve that order, and create chars for each line meeting your condition as a separate list.

Comment: This is confusing to me... seems like the loop unrolling is backwards, but thank you.