# how to write this in one line in the python way?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm quite new to python and wondering if I can convert the following for loop in to a one line of code in pythonic way:

```
w_topic = []
for line in lines: #lines is a list of strings
    word,topic = itemgetter(4,5)(line.split())
    w_topic.append((word,topic))
```

I have looked at list comprehensions but not sure how to apply it here? it is possible in one line? how do I know if something is doable is one line in the pythonic way?

```
[(w,t) for w,t in how to fill  here?]
```

Comment: Related: [Advanced Nested List Comprehension Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3766711/198633)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
get = operator.itemgetter(4,5)
w_topic = [get(line.split()) for line in lines]
```

Comment: if `lines` is a generator, representing a big dataset, using parantheses iso backets (making this function call return a generator itself) can help save memory `(get(line.split()) for line in lines)`

Answer (score 2):

> This is your one line

```
w_topic.extend([tuple(line.split()[4:6]) for line in lines])
```

I consider the following as complete code:

```
lines = ['0 1 2 3 word1 topic1','0 1 2 3 word2 topic2','0 1 2 3 word3 topic3']
w_topic = []

w_topic.extend([tuple(line.split()[4:6]) for line in lines])
print w_topic
```

result:

> [('word1', 'topic1'), ('word2', 'topic2'), ('word3', 'topic3')]