# Skip entry in generator expression

Tags: python, expression, generator, generator-expression

What is the best way to skip entries in a **generator expression** that are created using a function and another generator?

In essence, I am looking for an expression that looks like this:

```
some_iter = (some_function(_x, _y, **kwargs) or continue for _x, _y in some_generator(*x))
```

(but the `continue` statement obviously doesn't work in this context)

Functionally, it should act like this:

```
def some_iter(*x):
    for _x, _y in some_generator(*x):
        x = some_function(_x, _y, **kwargs)
        if x:
            yield x
```

Comment: You have to use nested generator: `(_x for _x in (function(_x) for _x in generator(*x)) if _x)` or `filter(None, (function(_x) for _x in generator(*x))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advanced Nested List Comprehension Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766711/advanced-nested-list-comprehension-syntax)

Comment: In python3.8, you can use assignment expressions `(y := function(_x) for _x in generator(*x) if y)` (I think)

Comment: By the way, why not using the function-style generator? It works perfectly fine and is more readable.

Comment: I might end up using the function-style generator, but the purpose of the question was to query if there was a way using the generator expression that I might not know of.

If only @coldspeed's answer would work with older versions of python!

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension allows to filter *and then* map. You want to manually `map` your function first.

```
gen = (x for x in map(function, generator(*args)) if x)
```

The above is for a `generator` that yields single arguments. You can use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) if it returns a `tuple` of arguments.

```
from itertools import starmap

gen = (x for x in starmap(function, generator(*args)) if x)
```

Finally, if you also need to pass in keyword arguments, you will need to rely on a `lambda` function.

```
gen = (x for x in map(lambda args: function(*args, **kwargs), generator(*g_args)) if x)
```

Although, note that at that point, the function-style generator might be more readable.

```
def gen(*x):
    for args in generator(*x):
        x = some_function(*args, **kwargs)
        if x:
            yield x
```

Comment: `function` isn't a builtin?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Hum you are right... Pycharm told me it was one and I blindly trusted it

Comment: @OlivierMelançon this is a helpful answer, but see my most recent edits... can `map()` still be applied if the function requires multiple arguments and keyword arguments?

Comment: @omegamanda No, but in that case you can use starmap, let me add a note on that

Comment: @OlivierMelançon thanks for the update, but i don't think this will work with the keyword arguments that also need to be passed to `some_function()`